# Emular efecto con logo intro

Tags: css, html5

tengo esta url http://buzzworthystudio.com/ en la que al ingresar aparece un efecto con el logo que tapa toda la pantalla de un color sólido para luego posicionarse al lado izquierdo de la página. Cómo podría emular este efecto.

Tengo este código https://codepen.io/MasterCharlz/pen/zojKEx que tiene un movimiento parecido pero depende de una acción del puntero, cómo podría cambiar el código para que el movimiento empieze cuando la página cargue.

Gracias de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Cambie su código Javascript por éste:

```
var navEl = $(".nav");
var fullscreen = $(".fullscreen");

setTimeout(() => {
fullscreen.addClass("shrunk");
navEl.addClass("expanded");
}, 1000);
```

Puede cambiar el 1000 que representa 1000 milisegundos = 1 segundo, por el tiempo que necesite que el logo se muestre.
Recuerde marcar la repsuesta como válida para ayudar a otras personas con su problema en el futuro. Suerte!

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Me sirvió mucho.